# Data not fully loaded from Core Data when being called by UICollectionView to display cell

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data, uicollectionview

I want to display some data in UICollectionView read from Core Data in viewDidLoad. However, when the UICollectionView is presenting its cells, the data has not been fully loaded yet. Thus, the UICollectionView is empty.

What I want to ask is how to make sure the data is ready before the UICollectionView starts to load its cells. Following is part of the code I'm working on.

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var allDishes = [AnyObject]()
    var categoryList = [String]()

    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: self.dishItemEntityName)
        var allDishes = self.context?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

        if let allDishes = allDishes {
            for dish in self.allDishes {
                let dish = dish as! DishItem
                if contains(self.categoryList, dish.category) {
                    continue
                } else {
                    self.categoryList.append(dish.category)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // MARK: Delegate Methods

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.categoryList.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called before `viewWillAppear`. You could call `reloadData` on the collection view in `viewWillAppear`.

Better: use a `NSFetchedResultsController` which will give many other benefits for memory management, performance and automatic updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly! Can I ask one more question please? Why is `NSFetchedResultsController` thread safe? How does this work differently compared to `NSFetchRequest`?

Comment: When populating a table view, the fetched results controller will always run on the main thread. Background core data threads should use child contexts of the main context - when you save such a child context, the main context gets updated and the FRC will automatically update the table on its own thread.

Answer (score 0):

Call **reloadData** at the end of viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    categoryCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. But thanks all the same! : )